# Names are not coming when fetch likes and comments from facebook page using facebook graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-page, facebook-comments

I am using this two calls to fetch likes and comments from Facebook GraphAPI:

1. https://graph.facebook.com/post_id/likes?access_token=page_token
2. https://graph.facebook.com/post_id/comments?access_token=page_token

and those call are working fine this is a regular response for Likes

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "id": "1713034225420001",
         "name": "Mariah Smit"
      },
   ],
   "paging": {
      "cursors": {
         "before": "MTcxMzAzNDI3NTQyMDAwMQZDZD",
         "after": "MTAyMTM0MzE4MzE5ODIzMTAZD"
      }
   }
}
```

this is a regular response for comments

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "created_time": "2018-02-16T16:50:04+0000",
         "from": {
            "name": "Jhon Smit",
            "id": "10214772022523290"
         },
         "message": "Test",
         "id": "191987714732076_191988141398700"
      }
   ],
   "paging": {
      "cursors": {
         "before": "9qRTFNVGczT1RrNE1EVT0ZD",
         "after": "WTI5dGJXVnVkRjlqZAFVT0ZD"
      }
   }
}
```

**The problem**

There is an user that has several facebook pages and in all the pages those two calls are working fine except for one of them where the names are not coming for comments and for likes I have no data at all

This is how it looks the response for likes

```
{
   "data": [

   ],
   "paging": {
      "cursors": {
         "before": "MTAyMTM0MzE4MzE5ODIzMTAZD",
         "after": "MTcyNjAxNjIzNTE3NTg0"
      }
   }
}
```

and this is how it looks for comments

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "created_time": "2018-01-25T20:08:10+0000",
         "message": "\ud83d\ude0f",
         "id": "326064837118298_322250134476435"
      },
      {
         "created_time": "2018-02-12T22:12:00+0000",
         "message": "\ud83d\udc4c",
         "id": "326064837118298_334229551171826"
      },
   ],
   "paging": {
      "cursors": {
         "before": "9UQT0ZD",
         "after": "WTI5dGJXVnVkRj"
      }
   }
}
```

Is this a privacy issue? Is there any way for a page to set names invisible for API calls?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: are you using a page token of that specific page?

Comment: And what exact role does the user have on that page - admin, or just one of the lesser roles?

Comment: Yes, I am using pages tokens

Comment: I don't know what role type is but the same user has several pages and only one has this problem